# How to display Object data correctly to view in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template, typescript-typings

I am learning Angular 2 and I am stumbled in one of my views that it's weird to see.

inside my `ts` code I have:

```
import { CompanyService } from '../../services/company.service';
import { Company } from '../../models/company';    
export class TestEssayComponent implements OnInit {
        company: Company;
        constructor(private companyService: CompanyService){}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCompany();
      }
    getCompany(){
        var company_id: number;
        company_id = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('company_id'));
        this.companyService.getById(company_id).subscribe(
          data => {
            var company = new Company;
            company = data.data;
            this.company = company;
            console.log(this.company);
          }
        );
     }
}
```

And in the html file I have:

```
<section class="content-header">
    <h1>New Test <small>{{company.name}}</small></h1>
</section>
```

And then this gives an error `"name of undefined"` but when I replace it with:

```
<section class="content-header">
        <h1>New Test <small>{{company}}</small></h1>
    </section>
```

this will show `[object Object]`. And in the console, data is filled.
So how to display it correctly in view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the safe-navigation operator `?.` to guard agains `null` or `undefined` while the data is not yet available

```
<h1>New Test <small>{{company?.name}}</small></h1>
```

You can also use `*ngIf` like

```
<h1 `*ngIf="company">New Test <small>{{company.name}}</small></h1>
```

to only render the element after the data becomes available.